# Is the story deeper if the characters are not aware of the symbolism?

Tags: showing-telling, metaphor, symbolism

https://youtu.be/f2QWxqNOtJg?t=218

In Game of Thrones 2, the king is made aware of the white stag, which is a symbol, and I was wondering if this kind of symbolism is there to have a completely different effect than when you put symbolism in the story, which the characters are not made aware of. Are these two intended to have completely different effects on the story, and which one is "deeper" or make the story "deeper"? I am wondering if this is related to the "show and don't tell" rule.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "deeper" so I can't make any sense out of your question.

Comment: Deeper, made more intellectual, adding more depth, etc.